# Wpf components dont resize with the window

Tags: layout, wpf-controls

My wpf components won't resize with my window, and it doesn't appear for other people.
For example my tab doesn't resize when I set windows state to maximized. 
It just stays the same, I tried adding some extra xaml code i found but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please show us the XAML so we can give accurate feedback. In general any explicit setting of Height and/or Width of any control is wrong if you want automatic resizing.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I reckon is you must have given hard coded widths & heights to the container your controls belong to. Say for example it belongs to a grid cell, you may have specified numerical values for height of the row & width of the column.

You have to instead specify the the height/width as *** or AUTO** as required.

"*" indicates *occupy the entire remaining space.*

"AUTO" indicates *occupy only the required amount of space.*

If you are using it in XAML file you may use it directly.

Ex:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

If you are using it in a code behind file you may use it in the following way:

```
GridLengthConverter conv = nwe GridLengthConverter();
ColumnDefinitions[n].Width = (GridLength)conv.ConvertFromString("*");
```

Answer (score 1):

What Container do you use to hold your wpf components in your window? Not all containers will resize the components inside itself.

StackPanel, WrapPanel, Canvas and TabControl do not resize while Grid, UniformGrid and DockPanel do.